# Canada Electronic Travel Authoristion for UK citizens travelling by air

Tags: visas, canada, uk-citizens, eta

Canada introduced an [entry requirement (eTA)](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/canada/entry-requirements) on 15th March 2016 for UK passport holders travelling by air to Canada. Land or Sea passengers are not affected.

However, Canadian authorities have stated that from 15 March 2016 until the autumn of 2016, travellers who don’t have an eTA can board their flight, as long as they have appropriate travel documents (eg a valid passport). During this time, border services officers can let travellers arriving without an eTA into the country as long as they meet the other requirements to enter Canada.

So, as a UK passport holder do I need an eTA or not? Does anyone know if I will have trouble flying to Canada from USA in June if I do not have one?

Surely they should just introduce the eTA with no exceptions. It will cause a lot less confusion!

Comment: The [official FAQ states](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=1235&top=16) that you should still get an eTA even though there's a leniency period. As for the confusion, I take it you haven't tried to fill out the form yet? [The form has some very inconsistent dropdowns and in several cases confusing/wrong entries](https://insideflyer.co.uk/2016/03/flying-canada-need-eta-thesaurus/) for UK citizens!

Comment: Note that the statements says that border services officers **can** allow entry without the eTA, not that they **will**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, you need an eTA, the rules are pretty clear on the [CIC](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp) (emphasis mine). So you shouldn't have a problem flying in without one in June, provided everything else is ok

> However, from March 15, 2016 until fall 2016, travellers who do not
>   have an eTA can board their flight, as long as they have appropriate
>   travel documents, such as a valid passport. During this time, border
>   services officers can let travellers arriving without an eTA into the
>   country, **as long as they meet the other requirements to enter Canada**

And as if to answer your specific question, once again the answer is **yes**, you need an eTA even if there's a [leniency period](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=1235&top=16)

> **Do I really need an eTA to fly to or transit through Canada since
>   there is a leniency period?**
>
> Yes, as of March 15, 2016, visa-exempt foreign nationals are expected
>   to have an eTA to fly to or transit through Canada.
>   [...] Before you travel to Canada — even if it is when you check in
>   for your flight — you can apply for an eTA using any device with an
>   internet connection, including a mobile phone. It takes just a few
>   minutes to complete the form. All you need to apply is a passport, a
>   credit card, and an email address.

With regards to your last statement, the leniency period is intended to *avoid* confusion, people have a hard time following rules as it is, this just gives them time to be familiar with the new ones. Imagine you hadn't heard that you need an eTA and upon arrival you're refused entry because the rule allows no exceptions !

Comment: @blackbird57 I guess the clues are in the terminology used. "During this time, border services officers **can** let travellers arriving without an eTA into the country"

Comment: @davidb yes, *as long as they meet the other requirements to enter Canada*